# Javascript url change

Tags: javascript

I have function which is changing url, with window.history.pushState Event.

for example:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "movies");
```

this works great.

but if my url is:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "movies/action");
```

it doesn't work correctly.

on every click, it pushes left 'movies' in url

```
http://localhost/movies/movies/action
http://localhost/movies/movies/movies/action
http://localhost/movies/movies/movies/movies/action
```

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Using an absolute path should solve it: `window.history.pushState(null, null, "/movies/action");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative path, you should change this to an absolute path:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "/movies/action");
```

When using a relative path it will create the URL differently depending on the current location (i.e. relative to the current URL).